# ZMQ message_t.data() clear data

Tags: c++, zeromq

In reference to this question:
[Zeromq: How to access tcp message in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901240/zeromq-how-to-access-tcp-message-in-c)

I managed to create a helloworld server that can print the contents of the sent messages pretty easily, however my issue is that I can't figure out a way to clear the buffer in the request variable.

Here's what I mean:

When I try and send a request such as:

```
tuna
```

For some reason the pointer returned by `request.data()` is initialised with 6 hexadecimal characters for some reason, and the message sent, after a `memcpy` ends up being:

```
tuna�
```

If I enter nothing as the message, the message becomes:

```
�q���
```

If I enter enough characters, the characters can overwrite it.
Additionally this data is kept in the variable, even if I re-initialise the `message_t` variable at the start of the loop.
This means that if I send a message of `Disestablishmentarianism`, and subsequently send another message of `Pro`, the resultant message is `proestablishmentarianism`.

Here's my code for reference:

```
    //sender loop
        using namespace std;
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);

int main(){
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:28641"); //28641 is the set to be standardised for this kind of communication
    string input = "";
    cout << "this is the client for communicating with Thalamus.\nTo start, input the name of the module to be used:";

    while(true){
        std::cout << "Type a config command:" << std::endl;
        getline(cin, input);
        zmq::message_t request(input.size()+1);
        //(char *)request.data() = ' ';
        std::string req = std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
        std::cout << req << std::endl;
        //std::cout << input;
        memcpy ((void *) request.data (), input.c_str(), input.size());
        socket.send (request);
        printf("%s\n",(char*)request.data());

        //  Get the reply.
        zmq::message_t reply;
        socket.recv (&reply);
        std::cout << "response:" << std::endl; 
        printf("%s\n",(char *)reply.data());
        //printf("%s", "moo");


    }


    return 0;
}


    //receiver loop
void Config_Interface(){
    //Config_Interaction uses ipc protocols as an interface to controlling and configuring the execution of the program.
    /*
        requirements:
            start stream
            stop stream
            pause/resume
    */
    zmq::context_t config_context(1);
    zmq::socket_t config_socket(config_context, ZMQ_REP);
    config_socket.bind ("tcp://*:28641");


    while(true){
        zmq::message_t request;

        config_socket.recv(&request);
        std::cout << "config update msg received:" << std::endl;
        std::string req = std::string(static_cast<char*>(request.data()), request.size());
        std::cout << req << std::endl;
        //Config_Parse(request.data()); //Function that will parse the command and update the config variables.
        std::cout << "--updated config--";

        zmq::message_t reply(7);
        memcpy ((void *) reply.data (), "got it", 6);
        config_socket.send (reply);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I've managed to find a work around by using:
   `snprintf ((char *) request.data (),input.size()+1,"%s", input.c_str() );` instead of `memcpy` but I feel as though it still doesn't quite answer the question of why the memory isn't cleared. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental to C++, but even after a ton of searching I still can't find it. :(

Comment: ZeroMQ sockets have internal "line-code" that helps the **Formal Commmunication Patterns Framework** deliver it's unique set of **Behavioral Model(s)** respective to the selected Library Primitive(s). You might want to make your post compatible with StackOverflow policy to include a **MCVE** = **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **Example** piece of code, so as to both repeat an objected trouble and validate any solution proposed to fix it. You code is not complete. There is missing both the ZeroMQ socket model setup and the infrastructure dismantling & termination.**+Enjoy StackOverflow**

Comment: Hey I've added the more complete code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```html
message_t(void* data, size_t len)

//std::string tmp = "example";
//message_t(tmp.c_str(), tmp.size());
```

to init